# Error in (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L, maxit = 100L, :

Tags: r, glm

how to fix

```
> Error in (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L,
> maxit = 100L,  :    pwrssUpdate did not converge in (maxit) iterations
```

my code

```
GLMM_1 = glmer(factor(Y)~factor(JK)+UMUR+factor(JKES)+JPYKT+factor(PLYN)+(1|ID)-1,
               data=eksekusi1,family = binomial(link = "logit"),
               control = glmerControl(tolPwrss=1e-10))
```

[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqXay.png)

I hope it can be fixed

Comment: Hi Edward, we can't completely solve your issue without an idea of your data, but my first thought would be whether the variables you are setting as factors have enough sample in each levels for the model to converge.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.